# Why Firebase returns Null on Lat and Lng?

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The error says its an unboxing of dataSnapshot.child("Latitude").getValue(Double.class) may produce a java.lang.NullPointer exception

Here is the warning:

> Unboxing of 'dataSnapshot.child("Longitude").getValue(Double.class)' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException' less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   This inspection analyzes method control and data flow to report possible conditions that are always true or false, expressions whose value is statically proven to be constant, and situations that can lead to nullability contract violations.
>   Variables, method parameters and return values marked as @Nullable or @NotNull are treated as nullable (or not-null, respectively) and used during the analysis to check nullability contracts, e.g. report NullPointerException (NPE) errors that might be produced.
>   More complex contracts can be defined using @Contract annotation, for example:
>   @Contract("*, null -> null") — method returns null if its second argument is null @Contract("*, null -> null; _, !null -> !null") — method returns null if its second argument is null and not-null otherwise @Contract("true -> fail") — a typical assertFalse method which throws an exception if true is passed to it 
>   The inspection can be configured to use custom @Nullable
>   @NotNull annotations (by default the ones from annotations.jar will be used)

My android app looks up coordinates of a room from Firebase and then puts a marker on a map for that location with some data. I keep getting a *`null`* on my request having gone through others answers I still haven't a solution for this and don't know what else to try. The coordinates are being send to Firebase using `location.getLatitude()` and `location.getLongitude()`.

```
public LatLng getCoordsFromFirebase(final String location) {
    if (!location.isEmpty()) {
        //Get the location for the room
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = database.getReference("locations/");
        DatabaseReference locationsRef = myRef.child(getBlock(location));
        DatabaseReference floorRef = locationsRef.child(getFloor(location));
        DatabaseReference roomRef = floorRef.child(location);
        roomRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.getChildren() != null) {
                    double latitude;
                    double longitude;
                    if (dataSnapshot.child("Latitude").exists() && dataSnapshot.child("Longitude").exists()) {
                            latitude = dataSnapshot.child("Latitude").getValue(Double.class);
                            longitude = dataSnapshot.child("Longitude").getValue(Double.class);
                        classDest = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Long or Lat were null!!!");
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                throw databaseError.toException();
            }
        });
    }
    return classDest;
}
```

Here is my Firebase for context:

[image: Firebase Table]

[image: Code where the values are being added to Firebase]

Comment: Are you sure your reference is correct?

Comment: have you check your location varibles value?

Comment: Yes its just the String name of the room. ie C134x ...and the reference is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `roomRef` points to a single room in the database. So you don't need to loop over `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` in `onDataChange()`:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("Latitude") && dataSnapshot.hasChild("Longitude")) {
        double latitude = dataSnapshot.child("Latitude").getValue(Double.class);
        double longitude = dataSnapshot.child("Longitude").getValue(Double.class);
        classDest = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Long or Lat were null!!!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the data type of your Latitude variable if you still getting this error then try to debug the variable and check it's data type.

Most commonly this error occur due to the wrong type `inserted` by us accidentely which mismatches with other records For example you insert Latitute as String or you totally forget to add Latitude record.

Comment: I did its going in as location.getLatitude() and location.getLongitude() Ill add a picture of where I'm writing the data to firebase.